# How to find pdf files cached in chrome of macbook pro

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac

I would like to find the temporary pdf files which I have opened in google-chrome. I am using macbook pro. Where can I find the cache file in my laptop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/755861/where-is-googles-file-cache-on-osx  Or this? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1977503

Comment: The answer mentions that the directory is hidden. Did you try searching it with Finder?

Comment: Finder [i.e.Spotlight] won't search hidden/system locations. & the Chrome cache storage isn't in human-readable form